# R Studio not recognizing shortcuts

Tags: rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I searched this forum and I know similar questions exist. However, none of the suggested solutions are not working for me.

I think it has something to with my keyboard but I tried everything with no luck.

Mainly,

1. I can't set a short cut for CTRL+r for "Run Current Line or Selection". In fact, I can't use "Ctrl+R" combo for anything because it turns in to "Ctrl+ 'some up/down arrow'.
2. Next, the "uncomment/comment lines' shortcut, "CTRL+SHIFT+C" is not working for me. Nothing happens.

Can anyone please help me fix the above issues? My productivity is down despite purchasing a new desktop.

Comment: What version are you using? Are those shortcuts shown for those commands in the shortcut window?

Comment: I am using Ver 1.3.959.

Comment: Yes they are from the shortcut window.

Comment: What if you install the preview version? https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem, after migrating to a new desktop computer, and in my case it was caused by AMD Radeon background processes taking over the shortcuts: https://community.amd.com/thread/227221

If you have a AMD graphics card, you may be experiencing the same problem. If that is the case, if you disable the processes `Radeon Desktop Overlay` and `Radeon Host Application` (they may have slightly different names in your system) the shortcuts should start working again in RStudio.

Comment: I had the same issue. If you dont want to disable the processes, you can also just open the "AMD Radeon Software" and assign different hotkeys. For example, the switch camera option uses strg+shift+C if you change this to something else the shortcut works in R Studio as intended.

Comment: Or just delete it by "backspace", then it will be assigned "NONE" and comment/uncomment works as expected in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just updated my "AMD software Pro Edition" to 23.Q1.1. Had to open the "AMD software Pro Edition" control panel and click the settings gear. Then GOTO the Hotkeys tab and toggle off Hotkeys.