# RStudio Comment shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+C) not working

Tags: rstudio

RStudio v. 1.4.1103
Trying to use keyboard shortcut to comment lines of code in R scripts and Notebook code chunks.
Ctrl+Shift+C has no effect on selected code lines.
Using the menu "Code", "Comment/Uncomment Lines" works as expected.
Checked keyboard shortcuts; "Tools", "Modify Keyboard Shortcuts..." and this shortcut appears to be set up properly.  Tried "Reset..." in this dialog with out success.
This functionality was working as expected in a previous version of RStudio.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I am using RStudio 1.4.1106 inside Windows 10 and I am having the same issue. 
When trying to set the shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+C inside the Modify Shortcuts window, R doesn't fill the shortcut with the command.
I imagine Windows is doing something with the input and not propagating to RStudio. Changed it to Ctrl+/ since then.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. Found the answer in this post.
[R Studio not recognizing shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413617/r-studio-not-recognizing-shortcuts)

The ctrl+shirt+C shortcut was being utilized by `AMD Software: Adrenaline Edition`. I disable hotkeys within that software and R studio responded as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was my problem, too! Thanks, I was going crazy over this.

Comment: No doubt, always hard to know where to look with keybindings...